# Is there the conditional single logout in WSO2 Identity Server?

Tags: wso2-identity-server

Currently we are using WSO2 IS 5.1. In a single logout process, is it possible that can only the session that has requested, has been logout but other shared session still has remained?

I want to ask better, how we can display in my web application an option list from other SP issuers that their SP sessions has made during SSO login, and then we make to choose which the session that want to log out and can send logout request for selected SP and also want that only selected session has been log outed. exists any suggestion or example?

thanks a lot

Comment: Are you inquiring how an SP can logout itself and at the same time logout some other specific SPs that are participated in the same IdP session?

Comment: No, a sort of reverse, first, is it possible to display in our web apps list of all service providers that have participated in the same IdP sessions and than select a service provider for sending a request logout on its behalf to to IdP. then want that only selected service provide is logout and no single logout process to be run for other service provider that participant in SSO. anyway, is it possible single logout request process run for a Specific categories of service providers not for all participated service providers?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to know the flow of single logout in WSO2 Identity Server.
In one Service Provider(SP) send the logout request to Identity Provider(IDP). Then IDP determine the session participant. If session participant exist then send the logout request IDP to SP. After SP issue a logout response to the IDP. After that IDP send the logout response to original logout request. Now all session participant terminated.
You can found more details [here](http://xacmlinfo.org/2013/06/28/how-saml2-single-logout-works/).
It seems by default IS can't achieve your requirement.